# GPIO23 (BCM) is busy when using /sys/class/gpio but I am able to use wiringPi pin 4 (GPIO23)

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I'm having a bit of trouble accessing GPIO23 using /sys/class/gpio/. To clarify a few terms (according to the table on [this page](http://wiringpi.com/pins/)):

- Header pin 16 is **BCM GPIO 23**, which is **wiringPi pin 4**.
- Header pin 11 is **BCM GPIO 17**, which is **wiringPi pin 0**.

I can turn on an LED attached to header pin 16 and 11 using the following wiringPi program:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
int main (void)
{
  int pin = 0; // or 4
  wiringPiSetup () ;
  pinMode (pin, OUTPUT) ;
  for (;;)
  {
    digitalWrite (pin, HIGH) ; delay (500) ;
    digitalWrite (pin,  LOW) ; delay (500) ;
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

And I can flash an LED attached to header pin 11 (GPIO pin 17, wiringPi pin 0) in the OS like so:

```
$ echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export
$ echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
$ echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
```

but when I try to access header pin 16 (GPIO pin 23, wiringPi pin 0) I get the following error message:

```
$ echo 23 > /sys/class/gpio/export 
-bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

Some more information:

```
$ ls /sys/class/gpio/
export  gpio17  gpiochip0  unexport
```

Bringing GPIO17 up when it is already up:

```
$ echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export 
-bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

The `gpio` tool that comes with wiringPi gives me a similar error. I know wiringPi uses a memory map to write to the GPIO so there appears to be some kind of problem with the OS.

Comment: The gpio is already exported.  Trying to export again gives that error.  Have you tried the echo 1 etc to the port?  By the way what model Pi are you using?

Comment: Does this happen after you've been mucking about for a bit, or is it a consistent issue after a reboot?